# Firebase query to find a subscriber is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my Firebase db looks like.

```
subscriber

u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223
   children: false
   empty: false
   id:"u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223"
   name: "JACKSON"
   smoker:false
```

I want to find the record which matches id = `u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223`.

Below is my code and its not able to retrieve the record

```
Query recentPostsQuery = mRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo("u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223");
        recentPostsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e("Count ", "" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    subscriber = postSnapshot.getValue(Subscriber.class);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

`Log.e` count statement is returning 1 record which is correct, but looks like my query is wrong, that is why I am unable to fetch record.

Comment: if you Log.e is printing out 1, then it is finding the record?

Comment: Most likely your `Subscriber` class doesn't match with the data structure. If you `Log.e("Key ", postSnapshot.getKey())` inside the loop, you should see that it prints the key/uid.

Answer (score 0):

Your query must return `String` value not a object of `Subscriber`, Complete object of `Subscriber` exsist at node - *u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223*

```
// With return String value which is u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223
mRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo("u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223");
```

Comment: I want to retrieve complete object.

Comment: Then use mRef.child("u36eD7PsOaf6uo0CGuGPBjC3Y223");

Comment: also i want to use this value somewhere else, so how will i get value out of this ondatachange method... i tried to set a class variable insider ondata change, but outside this function thats returning null :(

Comment: You can use callbacks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722888/how-to-use-callback-mechanism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131700/discussion-between-rasi-and-user7327850).